# .htaccess redirect keeping url when there is wordpress code involved

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two domains, alfa.com and beta.com.

Beta.com points to alfa.com subdirectory named "ae" by following htaccess-file. It works fine, but what should I add to code to keep beta.com URL and not the URL www.alfa.com/ae. There is also some wordpress-code in the beginning, so the last sector is the one I'm talking about (begin beta.com).

Here's the code. Any help would be appreciated. I'm totally stuck with this…

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php5/etc/  
AddHandler x-httpd-php52 .php
```

*WordPress:*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
</IfModule>
```

*beta.com:*

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?beta\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.alfa.com/ae/$1 [R=302,L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule .* index.html [L]
```

Comment: Why don't you use a separate vhost for beta.com which has the ae directory as document root?

Comment: @etagenklo +1 on that. Or rewrite to the directory path, instead of redirecting.